# Error connecting to a mongoose database in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB_NAME = 'eventdb';
const HOST = '127.0.0.1:27017';
mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://${HOST}/${DB_NAME}`,{useNewUrlParser:true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.log('Didn\'t connect properly!'));
```

And I am getting this output:

> Didn't connect properly!
> events.js:111
> throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
> ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received >undefined
> at checkListener (events.js:111:11)
> at _addListener (events.js:348:3)
> at NativeConnection.addListener (events.js:406:10)
> at Object. (/Users/sebastianc/Desktop/codeworks/exercises/assessments/weekly->assessment-6/server/Models/event-model.js:11:4)

can anyone shed some light on what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a callback function:

```
db.on('error', () => console.log('Didn\'t connect properly!'));
```

See related post on this: [TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898056/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-listener-argument-must-be-of-type-functi)

Comment: How did you debug that? was it experience? because the stack trace does not refer to that line of code at all

Comment: Also stumbled over this myself sometimes in the past. There were also not many options on your code to apply the error message accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go with connecting with mongoose like this.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${HOST}/${DB_NAME}`,{useNewUrlParser:true}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Mongo Error ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('MongoDB Connection Established');
    }
});
```